# message - You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, version, compatibility

"You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer. For a faster, safer browsing experience Upgrade Today"

This message is obviously linked to the fact that a user is using an old version if IE (IE7 or earlier) and Microsoft believes that they should be using later version (IE8+).  It also occurs if user is emulating an older browser via F12 (IE Developer Tools).

I have users report this on several unrelated sites. However what I would like to know is how come only certain sites trigger this message? (I am not a big IE user) Is it generated by the site or is it a browser feature?  Is it related to the number of visits to the site?

curious

Comment: That message is part of the web-site. It's been put up by the author of the web-site. Why would you want to prevent that message from showing up? It's up there for a good reason.

Comment: It is generated by the site. Most likely through [conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) or browser detection with javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. 
Interesting that they are linking to a Microsoft sponsored site for the image.

```
 !--[if lt IE 8]>
 <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
  <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products      
     /ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/
     assets /100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" 
    alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade 
    for free today."   /></a>
  </div>
  <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Yes, Microsoft want's to get rid of old versions of IE.